# What pythonic way is there to clean this list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, duplicates

Hello and thanks for your help. I have a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```py
list_balls = [{'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 0.9},
{'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.20},
{'id': '30042', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.75},
{'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 1}]
```

I need to clean this list leaving unique list of dictionaries. If there is two entries or more with the same Id, I need to pick the one with the highest value on air. If they have equal values on air and ids, I need to leave the one where source == 'store'. Therefore, the result in this case would be

```py
list_balls = [{'id': '30042', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.75},
{'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 1}]
```

I tried the following code to flag as keep = False for the ones that need to be taken out but it only works when there is two duplicates:

```py
for i in range(0, len(list_balls )):
    if len(list_balls ) > 1:
        #print(list_balls [i])
        for j in range(1, len(list_balls )):
            if (list_balls [i]['id'] == list_balls [j]['id']):
                if (list_balls [i]['air'] > list_balls [j]['air']):
                    list_balls [i]['keep'] = True
                    list_balls [j]['keep'] = False
print(list_pns)
```

I assume this double for loop is not the most efficient way to do this either so any other ideas are welcome. Thanks for your help

Comment: One thing you can definitely do with the existing code is take out the first if outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby
list_balls = [{'source': 'store', 'air': 0.9, 'id': '803371', 'is_used': False}, {'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.2, 'id': '803371', 'is_used': False}, {'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.75, 'id': '30042', 'is_used': False}, {'source': 'store', 'air': 1, 'id': '803371', 'is_used': False}]


#result = [max(list(v), key=lambda x: x["air"]) for k, v in groupby(sorted(list_balls, key=lambda x: x["id"]), lambda x: x["id"])]
result = [max(list(v), key=lambda x: (x["air"], x["source"] == "store")) for k, v in groupby(sorted(list_balls, key=lambda x: x["id"]), lambda x: x["id"])]
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'air': 0.75, 'id': '30042', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation'},
 {'air': 1, 'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store'}]
```

Comment: Thanks! this solution works but it does not take into account the 'source' when both 'ids' and  'air' are the same

Comment: So you need the data where 'source' == 'store' if the values of air are same?

Comment: Yes. If value of air and Id are the same.

Comment: `result = [max(list(v), key=lambda x: (x["air"], x["source"] == "store")) for k, v in groupby(sorted(list_balls, key=lambda x: x["id"]), lambda x: x["id"])]` ?

Comment: I like the idea, it is elegant. But I have the feeling that it is not very good in term of complexity. You need to sort first, then groupby, then iterate over groups to find the max.

Comment: In term of execution speed, on big lists, I get a x2 or x3 using groupby

Answer (score 1):

Simply with something like this :

```
list_balls = [{'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 0.9},
{'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.20},
{'id': '30042', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.75},
{'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 1}]

result = {}

for e in list_balls:
    if e['id'] not in result or (
          (e['air'], e['source'] == 'store') > 
          (result[e['id']]['air'], result[e['id']]['source'] =='store')
        ):
        result[e['id']] = e

result_list = list(result.values())

print(result_list)
```

Displays

```
[{'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 1}, {'id': '30042', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.75}]
```

You can compare directly tuples to compare on multiple criterion. Notice that True is always > False (1>0)

---

Speed execution compared to groupby and defaultdict solutions:

```
import random
from collections import defauldict
from itertools import groupby

list_balls = []
for _ in range(10000000):
    list_balls.append(
        {
            'source': random.choice(['store', 'donation']),
            'id': random.randint(0,10000),
            'air': random.randint(0,4)
        }
    )

def vanilla_filter_list(list_balls):
    result = {}

    for e in list_balls:
        if e['id'] not in result or (
              (e['air'], e['source'] == 'store') > 
              (result[e['id']]['air'], result[e['id']]['source'] =='store')
            ):
            result[e['id']] = e

    return list(result.values())

def groupby_filter_list(list_balls):
    return [max(list(v), 
                key=lambda x: (x["air"], x["source"] == "store")) for k, v in groupby(
        sorted(list_balls, key=lambda x: x["id"]),
        lambda x: x["id"])]

def collections_filter_list(list_balls):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    for ball in list_balls:
        d[ball["id"]].append(ball)

    return [
        max(group, key=lambda x: (x["air"], x["source"] == "store")) for group in d.values()
    ]

%%time
vanilla_filter_list(list_balls) # 5.52s

%%time
groupby_filter_list(list_balls) #14.3s

%%time
collections_filter_list(list_balls) #8.41s
```

Comment: I think there is an issue with `if e['id'] not in result` .It means that for first time your code "see" a new id it will add it the result (no matter what is the value of 'air' field)

Comment: yes, that is the point. Then value will be updated if it encounters a new dict with same id and a greater value of air.

Comment: OK - got it :-)

Comment: I'm curious to see where my solution fits on those times. I'm assuming faster than `groupby_filter_list` but slower than `vanilla_filter_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
all_id = set(i['id'] for i in list_balls)
new_list_ballls = []
for id_ in all_id:
    max_air = max(i['air'] for i in list_balls if i['id']==id_)
    max_air_count = sum(1 for i in list_balls if i['air']==max_air and i['id']==id_)
    if max_air_count==1:
        for i in list_balls:
            if i['id']==id_ and i['air']==max_air:
                new_list_ballls.append(i)
    else:
        for i in list_balls:
            if i['id']==id_ and i['air']==max_air and i['source'] != 'store':
                new_list_ballls.append(i)
```

**Output** :

```
[{'id': '30042', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.75}, 
{'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_balls = [{'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 0.9},
              {'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.20},
              {'id': '30042', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.75},
              {'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 1}]

grouped_data = defaultdict(list)

for entry in list_balls:
    grouped_data[entry['id']].append(entry)

final_list = []

for k, v in grouped_data.items():
    if len(v) == 1:
        final_list.append(v[0])
    else:
        # sort by air
        x = sorted(v, key=lambda k1: k1['air'], reverse=True)
        if x[0]['air'] != x[1]['air']:
            final_list.append(x[0])
        else:
            # decide by source
            if [x[0]]['source'] == 'store':
                final_list.append(x[0])
            elif [x[1]]['source'] == 'store':
                final_list.append(x[1])

for entry in final_list:
    print(entry)
```

output

```
{'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 1}
{'id': '30042', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.75}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first group by `id` with a defaultdict then get the maximum dictionary by `air` afterwards. If a tie occurs with `air` and `id`, then use `source` as a secondary `key` for [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max).

**Demo:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_balls = [
    {"id": "803371", "is_used": False, "source": "store", "air": 0.9},
    {"id": "803371", "is_used": False, "source": "donation", "air": 0.20},
    {"id": "30042", "is_used": False, "source": "donation", "air": 0.75},
    {"id": "803371", "is_used": False, "source": "store", "air": 1},
    {"id": "803371", "is_used": False, "source": "donation", "air": 1},
]

d = defaultdict(list)
for ball in list_balls:
    d[ball["id"]].append(ball)

result = [
    max(group, key=lambda x: (x["air"], x["source"] == "store")) for group in d.values()
]

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 1}, {'id': '30042', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.75}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing needless, only a pure python, almost.
Sort the list of dictionaries by `id`, then by negative values of `air` so that the largest ones go first, and then by `source` so that the entries with `store` go first. After that, the first entry is selected from each set  of dictionaries, which are grouped by `id`.

```
import pprint

list_balls = [
  {'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 0.9},
  {'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.20},
  {'id': '30042', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation', 'air': 0.75},
  {'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store', 'air': 1}
]
list_balls.sort(key=lambda k: (k['id'], -k['air'], 0 if k['source'] == 'store' else 1))
pprint.pprint([d for i, d in enumerate(list_balls) if i == 0 or list_balls[i - 1]['id'] != d['id']])
```

**Output:**

```
[{'air': 0.75, 'id': '30042', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'donation'},
 {'air': 1, 'id': '803371', 'is_used': False, 'source': 'store'}]
```